# ActiveMQ Artemis - stomp over websocket - frame type

Tags: websocket, activemq-artemis

I'm using Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.9.0 with the STOMP over Websocket connector.

When I look at the frame received, they are seen as binary frames by my client, which is a Chrome browser, even during the `CONNECT` frame:

[image: websocket binary frame]

I don't have this behaviour with Apache ActiveMQ 5.X (frames are seen as text).
I believe it is determined with the opcode from Websocket protocol https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-65

Is it the expected behaviour from Apache ActiveMQ Artemis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is the expected behavior from Apache ActiveMQ Artemis. It uses Netty for web socket support, and for web socket frames specifically it uses [io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.BinaryWebSocketFrame](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.9.0/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/protocol/websocket/WebSocketServerHandler.java#L160)

Comment: Thank you Justin for this clarification.

Comment: I'm using the latest Artemis and I still see binary messages send from the server to the client, just like the original question.

Is there any new configuration option in Artemis to force sending text messages to clients instead of binary ones?

Comment: Furthermore, Inspecting the frame, I can see a "isBinaryBody: true" and the companion "binaryBody" property.... 

Is there any way I can disable this binary behavior and send everything in plain text?

Comment: @Alberto, I recommend you ask a new question.